# Windows IupLUA, iupalarm - how to make it the topmost window?

Tags: windows, lua

I want to set the "topmost" attribute for iup.Alarm and iup.message dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to people on one of the iup forums, iup.Alarm and iup.Message cannot be set to the topmost window.